# summarize the table by states such as population under 10 meters by states.​

Tags: r

I need help with coding something in R. This is the question I'm trying to answer: summarize the table by states such as population under 10 meters by states.​ This is from an excel file, I already loaded the excel file in r studio but I'm struggling to code this.

This is exactly how the columns looks like in the csv file:

**pop| elevations| lecz| pop_source| year| NAME| STATE_NAME| POP2010**

Comment: If you put more effort into your question, it will be easier for others to help.  It will also help you learn better.  For example, you didn't even say which two columns you want to compare, or how you want them compared.  Also, attaching an image is not very helpful.  Try using `dput()` to post a small sample of the data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I re-edited my question. Would highly appreciate it if you can help me or suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you loaded your data into something called `raw_data`, then try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
summarized_data <- raw_data %>% 
    group_by(STATE_NAME) %>% 
    filter(year == max(year)) %>% 
    filter(elevations < 10) %>% 
    summarize(pop = sum(pop))
```

But it is very hard to know for sure since you didn't provide a sample of your data using something like `dput(raw_data)`.